# Cold air blows through supply vent when furnace is off

Tags: hvac, insulation, heating, ducts, central-air

I have separate units for 2 floors. On 2nd floor , out of 3 room and big loft area only 2 rooms are always cold (like 55 degree during winter) when doors are closed.

These rooms have 2 supply vents each and 1 return for each room.When I checked the supply vents , they are blowing cold breeze when furnace is off.

This does not happen on any other room’s supply vent. HVAC technicians checked and they didn’t see anything wrong. And these 2 rooms are on other side of sun. Not sure what is going on. There has to be some fix for this. This is driving me crazy. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Furnace blowers usually for a little bit after the furnace stops heating.  There should not be any cool/cold air blowing though the ducts after this.  Furnace blowers are usually all or none for blowing air though the ducts.  Is the blowing pressure the same all the time or does it reduce after furnace stops?  Might be a leak that lets outside air in those ducts.

Comment: When furnace is on, it is blowing hot air. After furnace is off, in few minutes It’s soft cold breeze, but high enough to cool the room to higher 50 degrees.

Comment: so the two cold rooms are delivering cold air to the heated room ?

Comment: No, it’s not. But these rooms are always cold during winter, if doors are closed

Comment: With the furnace blowers working, does it seem as strong in those rooms as the other rooms or weaker?  Thinking the ducts for those cold rooms might have disconnected a bit, not enough to stop blowing, but enough to let cold air in when not blowing.

Comment: HVAC technician was able to check the ductwork in attic and he did not find any leak. But he found insulation on attic above these rooms are low. Have insulators company coming next week. Let’s see